# PatternMatchingEventHandler Ignoring the pattern that I haven't set into its attribute

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I am using Watchdog to Keep an eye on a folder where my Machine is Generating CSV files. But Before generating CSV file my machine is generating Temporary file and then its get converted to proper CSV. So to ignore the temporary file that has been placed into the folder which is being watched, I used PatternMatchingEventHandler.

The Code for the same is Given below

```
class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
        print(args[0])
        self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, args[1])
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = Handler(patterns=["*.CSV"], ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"], ignore_directories=True)
        #self.event_handler = Handler()

    def run(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()
```

When I place a file with extension .temp into the folder that is being watched, the observer ignores the file. Despite giving **"*.tmp"** in the ignore_function attribute it ignored **"
.temp"** file. How to ensure that my handler is working properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the patterns argument you have provided. It will ignore everything that isn't a *.csv, which includes .temp and .tmp files. If you would like to raise events for .temp files you will need to provide that to the patterns argument:

`self.event_handler = Handler(patterns=["*.CSV","*.temp"], ignore_directories=True)`

The ignore_patterns argument if for ignoring some patterns that meet the criteria in patterns:

`self.event_handler = Handler(patterns=["*.CSV"], ignore_patterns=["temp"], ignore_directories=True)`

This will allow all CSV files, but disallow "temp.csv"